# Need assistance with loop to iteratively add to sum variable in Assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, masm, irvine32

I'm trying to convert the following C++ code into Assembly (MASM, Irvine32):

```
const int SIZE = 10;

int numbers[SIZE] = {10,60,20,33,72,89,45,65,72,18};
int limit = 50;
int index = 0;
int sum = 0;

while( index < SIZE )
{
    if( numbers[index] <= limit )
    {
        sum = sum + numbers[index];         // sum += array[index];
    }
    index++;
}
```

If anyone could clear up where I'm going wrong -- I'm getting errors at L1: it's just spouting out "+10". I believe it's because I cannot translate sum=sum+numbers[index] into Assembly. If anyone could help me do that it would be fantastic. My attempt at translating it (lines starting from "total: mov esi, offset numbers" to "inc index") is obviously incorrect.

```
.data
SYZ = 10
numbers DWORD 10, 60, 20, 33, 72, 89, 45, 65, 72, 18
limit DWORD 50
index DWORD 0
sum DWORD 0

.code
main PROC
mov eax, index
mov ebx, SYZ
top: cmp eax, ebx
jae next
jb total

total: mov esi, OFFSET numbers
mov ecx, limit

cmp [esi], ecx

jbe L1

L1: add eax, ebx

inc index

jmp top

next: mov edx, sum

call WriteInt



exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Kind of unrelated to the actual question, but I don't think the "jb total" instruction is necessary, if "jae next" doesn't jump it will fall through to the next instruction (which has the label total) anyways, meaning it's a redundant check.

Comment: thank you for that check, you make sense it's redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditional branch that implements the `if` is wrong.  It should look like:

```
top:
...
    cmp [esi], ecx
    ja L1               ; conditional jump *over* an ADD instruction
    add eax, [esi]      ; [esi] is array[index] if you increment ESI properly...
L1: inc index
    jmp top
```

In your C++, you can see that if `numbers[index] <= limit` then you want to update the sum, otherwise just increment the index and go back to the "top"; aka recheck the stopping condition.

Your original asm code was doing a condition check and then continuing regardless of the result.

```
    cmp [esi], ecx
    jbe L1               ; jump or fall-through to L1, condition irrelevant
L1: add eax, ebx
```

The C++ equivalent of your original asm is:

```cpp
if( numbers[index] <= limit )
{
}

    sum += ebx;
    index++;
```

I'm not sure if this will solve all of your problems, but it will definitely solve one of them.

Comment: Your proposed new fragment of the loop still doesn't add another memory access to the loop besides the `cmp`, so it's not accessing `numbers[index]`.  From what I can tell from the mess in the OP's loop, it's accessing `numbers[0]` every iteration.  You've correctly identified on problem, which is that the conditional branch needs to jump *over* something, not just to the next instruction whether it falls through or is taken, but `add eax, ebx` certainly doesn't implement `sum += numbers[index];` because nothing puts the array value into EBX.

Comment: Also it's not *otherwise increment the index*.  You *always* increment the index regardless of the branch condition (`add esi, 4` to move the pointer).  Perhaps you meant "otherwise *just* increment the index (without doing anything else)".

Comment: Oh, I missed the last line of your answer where you say this might not be a complete solution.  Sorry, didn't notice that until after downvoting.  Saying "try this" is usually a bad way to start an answer, especially when it doesn't actually solve all the problems, so that gave me a bad impression of this answer before I got to the part where you eventually explain why.

Comment: I made an edit to make your answer more readable, IMO (and so I could remove my hastily cast downvote).  Anyway yeah, this is just one of multiple showstopper problems in the code in the question; I added a hint at another one in my edit to your first code block.

Answer (score 0):

```
.data
SYZ = 10
numbers DWORD 10, 60, 20, 33, 72, 89, 45, 65, 72, 18
limit DWORD 50
index DWORD 0
sum DWORD 0

.code
main PROC
mov eax, index
mov ebx, SYZ
mov esi, OFFSET numbers
mov ecx, limit
mov edx, 0

top: cmp eax, ebx
jae next
cmp [esi], ecx
ja L1
add edx, [esi]
L1: inc index
mov eax, index
add esi, 4
jmp top

next: mov sum, edx
      mov eax, sum
      call WriteInt
```